# Seeking ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest() explanation

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

What is the meaning of "10" in this code below?

I've been searching for it for a long time and I have no idea what it's actually about.

[image: smileRandomForest]

Comment: It is the number of decision trees in the forest.

Comment: Please always provide code as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: Having 10 Bootstrap replicates is absurd. There is no way that the error will converge with so few trees. I would start with b=501, with moderate sample sizes i often start with 1001 and adjust the parametre based on the number of bootstraps that stabilize the global error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random Forest is a machine learning algorithm and like every other algorithm, it has some hyperparameters. 10 is the no. of decision trees that Random Forest will use to make a prediction.

Every decision tree will give its output for the data you pass and based on the decision of those trees your classifier will produce its prediction. It all happens internally so you don't have to worry about the algo itself.

Just try to play with this no. to find which suits your data best.